# Яке походження слова "навзаєм", і як правильно його вживати?

Tags: значення-слів, вживання-слів

У відповідь на привітання зі святом чи побажання здоров'я завжди говорю *взаємно* (або *дякую, взаємно*).

Останнім часом дуже рідко чую у відповідь *взаємно*, натомість вживають варіант *навзаєм*. Це слово є милозвучним, але абсолютно новим для мене.

Яке походження слова *навзаєм*? Чи є воно коректним/правильним/рекомендованим у розмові? Чи була якась подія, яка стала каталізатором частішого використання цього слова останнім часом?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[Словник української мови](http://sum.in.ua/s/navzajem) позначає слово *навзаєм* як діалектне. Наголос на другому складі.

> **НАВЗА́ЄМ**, присл., діал. Взаємно. Знов регіт розлігся, знов жарти
>   навзаєм (Леонід Первомайський, II, 1958, 318); Зустрічаючись, іноки
>   цілують навзаєм руки (Павло Загребельний, Диво, 1968, 255).

Словник української мови: в 11 томах. — Том 5, 1974. — Стор. 29.

Дійсно, останнім часом вживається частіше, аніж *взаємно*. Напевне, щоб уникати можливих аналогій з російським *взаимно* (пересторога щодо калькування). А також, мабуть, тому, що співзвучно з іншими прислівниками, яких є багато, що починаються з на-: *навмисне*, *наперекір*, *напоказ*, *навпочіпки*, *нашвидку*, *навколішки* тощо.

Comment: "Навзаєм" ще й вимовляти дещо простіше (мені, як мінімум), бо комбінаця "мн" у "взаємно" трохи незручна.

Answer (score 0):

Новѣший [*Словник української мови*](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8_%D1%83_20_%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%85) [*у 20 томах*] вже не маїть позначки *діалектне*:

> [**НАВЗА́ЄМ**](//sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=53476&page=1705), *присл*. Те саме, що **взає́мно**.

---

*Доповненнє від себе, в котрому також зібрані «слушні» зауваги від відписів до видалених недовідповѣдѣв.*

То правда, же ляська маїть [*nawzajem*](//wsjp.pl/do_druku.php?id_hasla=51461&id_znaczenia=5159823), але то не єʼ доводом проти *взаємно* через низка причин.

*Перше* і очевидне. Якшчо сусѣдня мова маїть такого ж слова, то не значить, же то слово відти.

*Друге* і останнє. За такими думками можна виступати і проти *взаємно*. Бо ляська цѣлком маїть такого кореня: [*wzajemny*](//wsjp.pl/do_druku.php?id_hasla=34943&id_znaczenia=4050116), [*wzajemność*](//wsjp.pl/do_druku.php?id_hasla=51467&id_znaczenia=5151807). І взагалі єʼ мовознавча думка від [ЕСУМ-а](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%94%D0%BC), див. другий пункт:

> - очевидно, результати лексикалізації виразу псл. **ѵъ zajьmъ*, утвореного з прийменника *ѵъ*(*n*) та іменника *zajьmъ*, похідного від дієслова *zajьmati* (корінь *jьm-*/*ję-*, той самий, що і в дієсловах *ма́ти, займа́ти, я́mu, йня́ти*);
> - можливо, що прикметник *взаємний* в українську мову, як і в чеську, запозичено з польської;
> - р. *взаи́мный*, бр. *узае́мны*, п. *wzajemny*, ч. *vzájemný*, слц. *vzájomný*, вл. *wzajomny*, болг. *взаи́мен*, м. *взаемен*, *заемен*, схв. *у́зајаман*, слн. *vzajémen*;

Припускаю, причина тому *єм*. Тому декотрі чистомовцї взагалѣ [можуть](//fb.com/7PINYENKO/posts/333581133915783/) порадити слова як [*обопільно*](http://services.ulif.org.ua/grinch/Entry/search/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE), [*обоюдно*](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) ітд. Але маю зауваги.

- Там слово *можливо*.
- Кореня *jьm-*, *ję-* самі по собі непрості, бо мають дуже-дуже багато різних похідних. Нагадаю також про *-взаїм-*, котрого тут не розглядали окремо.

І про всяк, слово *навза*м* не нове. Наприклад можна знайти як записане, а отже словно вже існувало, в:

- листѣ, [1893 року](//l-ukrainka.name/Corresp/1893/18930223.html#Line4), Лесї Українки до Драгоманова;

  > Остаточно» (як кажуть галичани) я ніяк не можу постерегти логіки в поступуванні «січовиків» та й інших – то вони з тими попами **навзаєм** лаються і «собак вішають», то знов усякі гречності і прихильності строять для якихсь там клинів.
- книзѣ *Крашанка русинам и полякам на Великдень 1882 року*, [1882 року](//books.google.com.ua/books?id=mI3ofKCaQpgC&pg=PA13&q=%22%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%22), Кулеша:

  > Взива́ючи себе́ **навза́ем** Христо́вим проти́вниками, обі́дві сто́роні хапа́ють за по́лу вся́кого зустрі́чного и попері́чного, оббрі́хують сво́іх антакгоні́стів и грубия́нськими и найделікатні́йшими вира́зами, лестя́ть и насміха́юцця, вгово́рюють и знуща́юцця, блага́ють и погро́жують, обма́нюють и тира́нять, підкупо́вують и вбива́ють на смерть, аби́ ті́лько поперетя́гувати люде́й иш чужо́і фа́брики суеві́рства у свою́ вла́сну.

…ітд. І тут згадані лише класіки.